# How to print javascript data in Python terminal

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I have a javascript file, an html file and a python file. In the Java script function, a data is generated as a result of the event and I can see this data in the browser console. I would like to see this data in python as well. I made the website in a program called Hype4 and javascript and html files were generated automatically. I wrote the javascript function and the python file, but I cannot send data to python from the js function.

Python File:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import json
import pandas as pd



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("cafeproje.html")

@app.route('/receiver', methods = ["POST"])
def receiver():
    data = request.get_json()
    df = pd.read_json(data)
    print(data)
    return jsonify(data)

    
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Html File:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge" />
    <title>CafeProje</title>
    <style>
        html {
            height:100%;
        }
        body {
            background-color:#FFF;
            margin:0;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- copy these lines to your document head: -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=320" />

    <!-- end copy -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- copy these lines to your document: -->

    <div id="cafeproje_hype_container" class="HYPE_document" style="margin:auto;position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;"></div>
    <script src="static/js/cafeproje_hype_generated_script.js"></script>    

    <!-- end copy -->
    


    <!-- text content for search engines: -->

    <div style="display:none" aria-hidden=true>

        <div>Garson Seçiniz</div>
        <div>0</div>
        <div>Garson İlgili miydi?</div>
        <div> Arga Tek. Hizmetinizde</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>Garson Titiz miydi?</div>
        <div>Garson Hızlı mıydı?</div>
        <div>Evet</div>
        <div>Tuvaleti Kullandınız mı?</div>
        <div>Hayır</div>
        <div>Anketimiz Bu Kadardı Teşekkürler</div>
        <div>Tuvaletler Temiz Miydi?</div>

    </div>

    <!-- end text content: -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript Function:

```js
function veriGonder (hypeDocument, element, event){
    
    if (sayfaNo == "1") {
    
        var id = idKaydet;
        var sayfa = sayfaNo;
        var garson = garson;
        var oy = "NONE";
        var secenek = "NONE";
        
        datas = [{ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, garson: garson }];     console.log("Sayfa 1 Gönderildi: ");
        console.log(datas);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"/receiver",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, garson: garson })
        });
    }
    
    
    else if (sayfaNo == "2") {
    
        var id = idKaydet;
        var sayfa = sayfaNo;
        var garson = "NONE";
        var oy = oyMiktari;
        var secenek = "NONE";
        
        datas = [{ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, oy: oyMiktari }];      console.log("Sayfa 2 Gönderildi: ");
        console.log(datas);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"/receiver",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, oy: oyMiktari  })  
        });
    }
    
    else if (sayfaNo == "3") {
    
        var id = idKaydet;
        var sayfa = sayfaNo;
        var garson = "NONE";
        var oy = oyMiktari;
        var secenek = "NONE";
        
        datas = [{ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, oy: oyMiktari }];      console.log("Sayfa 3 Gönderildi: ");
        console.log(datas);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"/receiver",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, oy: oyMiktari })   
        });
    }
    
    else if (sayfaNo == "4") {
    
        var id = idKaydet;
        var sayfa = sayfaNo;
        var garson = "NONE";
        var oy = oyMiktari;
        var secenek = "NONE";
        
        datas = [{ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, oy: oyMiktari }];      console.log("Sayfa 4 Gönderildi: ");
        console.log(datas);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"/receiver",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, oy: oyMiktari })   
        });
    }
    
    else if (sayfaNo == "5") {
    
        var id = idKaydet;
        var sayfa = sayfaNo;
        var garson = "NONE";
        var oy = "NONE";
        var secenek = secenek;
        
        datas = [{ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, secenek: secenek }];       console.log("Sayfa 5 Gönderildi: ");
        console.log(datas);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"/receiver",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, secenek: secenek })    
        });
    }
    
    else if (sayfaNo == "5m1") {
    
        var id = idKaydet;
        var sayfa = sayfaNo;
        var garson = "NONE";
        var oy = oyMiktari;
        var secenek = "NONE";
        
        datas = [{ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, oy: oyMiktari }];      console.log("Sayfa 5m1 Gönderildi: ");
        console.log(datas);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"/receiver",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: idKaydet, sayfa: sayfaNo, oy: oyMiktari })   
        });
    }       
}
```

Auto-generated javascript code by Hype4 (Share link as it doesn't fit here):
https://www.codepile.net/pile/wA75kWrj

Comment: it would be good to give more details about what's exactly not working: is the ajax call not being triggered? is it its data not being sent? is it flask not recognising the URL?

Comment: @CamiEQ Honestly, neither do I know exactly, nor do I know how to check it. Only the function works because I run the python file, when I open the site and the required clicks etc. when I do, the console.log in the function is running and I can see it in the browser console.

Comment: add `print` as the first line of `def receiver():` . Can you see this print?

Comment: Do you see the requests in "Network" tab of Webdev tools too? What response does it return there? Do you see the AJAX requests logged in the Python console where you're running the Flask app? The more details you'll share, the higher chance someone can help you.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko
I did what you said, there is no change in the network window.

Comment: @balderman i did what you said, now i get an error like this:
'ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>'

Comment: share the latest code.

Comment: @balderman I posted the python code I changed below.

Answer (score 0):

@balderman

Python:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import json
import pandas as pd



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("cafeproje.html")

@app.route('/receiver', methods = ["POST"])
def receiver():
    print("we are here")
    data = request.get_json()
    df = pd.read_json(data)
    print(data)
    return jsonify(data)

    
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I did not change other codes.

Output:

```
* Serving Flask app "cafeproje" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 250-177-957
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2020 12:18:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2020 12:18:28] "POST /receiver HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Ortak Drive'lar/Arga Tek/Tunahan/ProjeCafeDeneme/cafeproje.py", line 17, in receiver
    df = pd.read_json(data)
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 585, in read_json
    path_or_buf, encoding=encoding, compression=compression
  File "/Users/tunahan/opt/anaconda3/envs/CafeProjesiDeneme/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 200, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: from the line `df = pd.read_json(data)` that is coming from your code it looks like that `data` is not a valid json. I think `data` is already a python dict. All you have to do is to pass this dict to pandas.

Comment: Yes! finally. All I had to do was disable or make the panda available. I can see data in Python right now. Thank you so much @balderman

Answer (score 0):

please read the documentation for [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas-read-json):

> Parameters path_or_buf **a valid JSON str**, path object or file-like object

you're not passing there **a valid JSON str**. You are passing there a dictionary which you created one line higher:

```
data = request.get_json() # this returns a dictionary
```

which is why you are getting error that the parameter is a dictionary:

```
Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>
```

remove the line `data = request.get_json()` and pass into `read_json()` the response as a **json string**